# JPA, Map entity Person which contains class of type Name

Tags: jpa, orm, entity

I have an entity Person which consists of a name Attribute

```
@Entity
public class Person {
      // ...
      //@Transient 
       private Name name;
      // ...
}
```

I dont want to store "name" in an extra table... I mark name as transient so it is not stored in the underlying database.

What I want is to map the attribute "name" to columns "first_name" and "last_name" in the database.

For example I can create a person like `new Person(new Name("John","Doe"));`

How can I achieve a mapping that the underlying table contains two additional columns first_name and last_name and the contents are the strings which I get from the name attribute?

The table, based on the person entity should look like

id|first_name|last_name
1 |John      | Doe
2 |Jane      | Doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use embeddables:

```
@Embeddable
public class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then use it like.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
      // ...
      private Name name;
      // ...
}
```

Read more about embeddables in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables